# How to provide a REST API into 3rd Party data?

Tags: rest, dropbox, zapier, ifttt, omnifocus

I use OmniFocus a ton and I'd really like to be able to connect my data there to other things (Zapier, IFFFT, Beeminder, etc).  There's a lot of support for putting data **into** OmniFocus through these services, but I can't find any support for getting data out of OmniFocus.

In thinking about this, I realized my question isn't really about OmniFocus but rather about building a connector to a service that I don't own.  So this is my scenario:

- I have data on some publicly accessible web service (in the case of OF, it's Dropbox)
- I want to build and host some sort of application that accesses that data and parses it and then provides a REST API that other servers can then query.
- Ideally I'd like to make this service available to others - this seems tricky because they have to somehow enable my application to read their data.

I'm a fairly experienced software dev but I have zero experience with web applications or cloud applications.  I'm not looking for a super in-depth answer here, but more of a general sketch of how this would work (or a confirmation that this really isn't feasible).

Comment: As far as programmatically interacting with files in Dropbox is concerned, information on using the Dropbox API can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/